# Ubuntu 18.04 Server - disable, uninstall, delete, erradicate ubuntu desktop!

Tags: 18.04, gdm

Before you tell me this is a duplicate query, I call horse hockey!!

I have implemented every searched comment to destroy ubuntu desktop on this server, and there so far has been absolutely NO WAY TO DO IT.

Now, I am happy to be shown to be a novice Ubuntu/Linux person...

I have tried all the form suggestinons.. and gdm ALMOST completely dies a death, but it has an after life.

I run the commands and have to do it in a Ctrl Alt T terminal and then if I stop the gdm service it causes a system fault.

I try to do an override:
sudo dd of=/etc/init/gdm.override

in a desperate attempt to keep gdm from loading on boot... but it always still does.

Please save me....  I admit this is a test machine and I can just reinstall the OS, but I'm trying to become competent in dealing with such issues.

Please tell me how stupid I am!!

Comment: I've run the kill/remove/stop gdm commands so much now, they do nothing and I just get a blue screen with a minimal desktop.  If I try to do anything with lighdm, the system tells me.. hey dude it's not running you idiot.. (paraphrase).

Comment: I am desperate to get a text/command interface at boot and to know how to make this happen when I need it.  The server is a blade and I am trying to be able to remotely connect.  Unfortunately SSH connection is acting like a torture interrogation, so if I can at least reinstall the whole desktop and remote desktop to the box, I can at least dispense with the KVM kludge from an Intel Modular server that they abandoned service on.

Comment: Ubuntu Server does not have a desktop; it's all text based.  Your almost-rant is very unclear, and sorry, but I have no idea what you want?  (and it contradicts - `ubuntu-desktop` is a package not found on server! so if you added it, remove it in the opposite manner to which you installed it, ie. if you `sudo apt install` you `sudo apt remove` the package..)

Comment: Please rephrase your question in a way that explains why you have tried these things, and how you even got a desktop service on a server in the first place. As it stands, your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first change default runlevel to console login with

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

and then remove desktop packages with `apt-get` (or `aptitude`):

```
sudo apt-get purge gdm3 lightdm ubuntu-desktop
```

other GNOME-related stuff may be removed with commands below (but be careful):

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep -i GNOME | awk '{print $2}')
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | grep -i desktop | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}')
sudo apt-get auto-remove
```

Comment: Thank you.  sudo systemctl set-default multi-usr.target
result: Failed to set default target: Unit file multi-usr.target does not exist.

The remaining commands however did the trick.

I had installed the desktop... that's one reason I wanted to uninstall it.

I had already tried numerous similar commands to uninstall actually I think the GNOME related stuff command did it.

Regards.

Comment: The third set of commands removed a lot of extra stuff from my system that I didn't expect.  apache2, zoneminder, corosync, dnsutils, ffmpeg, imagemagick, python, php, etc.  Not only that, but it purged configuration files!  I realize you said "be careful", so I can't complain - it's on me.